# Regression in SPSS

Tags: spss, modeling, probit

I have collected data from 400 students through questionnaire on .5 likert scale about their learning of different skills when they are taught by Masters and M,Phil and PhD qualified teachers.

I have 3 IDV and and 7 DV. Data only collected through students.

The purpose is to find the impact of teachers qualification on students different skills.

Which regression model should I use in SPSS? Kindly also guide about procedure.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your measurement of student's skill. In your objective "**to find the impact of teachers qualification on students different skills**", you clearly have two variables; namely '**teacher's qualification**' (seems categorical variable) and '**student's skill**'. [As you're interested in analyzing the impact of one on another variable, it becomes bivariate study]

Now, if you are measuring it on non-metric scale, you can simply check association between the two, so cross-tabulation would be suitable.

If it's measured on metric scale, then regression or 1-way anova would be suitable. However, you need to make sure to control for other factors, which might affect the relationship between the two variables. Also, checking for assumptions before you run any test is recommended.